# Try and catch in r while scraping

Tags: r, try-catch

I have data table(npi1_list) which contains ID number and based on the number am doing the web scraping from the website,npi list will match the ID number in the website and pull the records for me.

```
library("rvest")
library("data.table")    
final<- NULL
    for(i in 8000:200000){
    url<-paste("http://www.npinumberlookup.org/getResultDetails.php?
    npinum=",npi1_list[i,1],sep='')
    webpage<-read_html(url)
    Name<- html_nodes(webpage, 'table:nth-child(8) tr:nth-child(1) td~ td+ td ,
    table:nth-child(6) tr:nth-child(1) td~ td+ td')
    rank_data <-html_text(Name)
    final <- rbind(final,rank_data)
    print(i)
    Sys.sleep(1)
    }
```

This works fine but at times the error is displayed connection timeout 80 port error and again then I have to initialise i from where the loop got terminated and re-run the for loop.How to do implement try and catch option in above for loop so that I can automate till line no 200000.

Comment: Why aren't you just using the [downloadable full database](http://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPI_Files.html) and/or the weekly updates? Hammering a site — they **explicitly state** a minimum of [20s crawl-delay](http://www.npinumberlookup.org/robots.txt) — is not cool for data esp you can find in bulk elsewhere. They also are not an authoritative source, so I'd also worry about data integrity issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
library("rvest")
library("data.table")    
final<- NULL
for(i in 8000:200000){        
    repeat{
        successful = T   
        tryCatch({
            url<-paste("http://www.npinumberlookup.org/getResultDetails.php?
            npinum=",npi1_list[i,1],sep='')
            webpage<-read_html(url)
            Name<- html_nodes(webpage, 'table:nth-child(8) tr:nth-child(1) td~ td+ td ,
            table:nth-child(6) tr:nth-child(1) td~ td+ td')
            rank_data <-html_text(Name)
            final <- rbind(final,rank_data)
            print(i)
        }, error = function(e){
            print(e)
            print(paste0('connection error on ', i))
            successful <<- F
        }) 
        Sys.sleep(1)
        if(successful)
            break
    }
}
```